# Fineuploader -> get folder and uploadname on complete

Tags: php

I use Fineupload with the default server config (example.php, found here : https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php)

And this is my code :

```
$('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: 'example.php'
    },
     validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif']
    }
}).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {
        $(this).append('<img src="upload2/'+ fileName +'" alt="' + fileName + '">');
    }
});
```

This works fine, but I want to get my uploadname and folder name in my JS callback. The fileName is not the renamed name (if it has to be renamed).
How can I get this ?

Edit :

This works fine for the upload name :

```
if (responseJSON.success) {
        $(this).append('<img src="upload2/'+ responseJSON.uploadName +'" alt="' + fileName + '">');
    }
```

And in my PHP file :

```
// To return a name used for uploaded file you can use the following line.
$result['uploadName'] = $uploader->getUploadName();

 /**
 * Get the name of the uploaded file
 */
public function getUploadName(){
    return $this->uploadName;
}
```

But I do not know how to get the extension type or the path name. This is my code for select the path :

```
 /**
 * Process the upload.
 * @param string $uploadDirectory Target directory.
 * @param string $name Overwrites the name of the file.
 */
public function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $name = null){

    if (is_writable($this->chunksFolder) &&
        1 == mt_rand(1, 1/$this->chunksCleanupProbability)){

        // Run garbage collection
        $this->cleanupChunks();
    }

    // Check that the max upload size specified in class configuration does not
    // exceed size allowed by server config
    if ($this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size')) < $this->sizeLimit ||
        $this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')) < $this->sizeLimit){
        $size = max(1, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';
        return array('error'=>"Server error. Increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to ".$size);
    }

    // is_writable() is not reliable on Windows (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-executable.php#111146)
    // The following tests if the current OS is Windows and if so, merely checks if the folder is writable;
    // otherwise, it checks additionally for executable status (like before).

    $isWin = (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN');
    $folderInaccessible = ($isWin) ? !is_writable($uploadDirectory) : ( !is_writable($uploadDirectory) && !is_executable($uploadDirectory) );

    if ($folderInaccessible){
        return array('error' => "Server error. Uploads directory isn't writable" . (!$isWin) ? " or executable." : ".");
    }

    if(!isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])) {
        return array('error' => "No files were uploaded.");
    } else if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']), 'multipart/') !== 0){
        return array('error' => "Server error. Not a multipart request. Please set forceMultipart to default value (true).");
    }

    // Get size and name

    $file = $_FILES[$this->inputName];
    $size = $file['size'];

    if ($name === null){
        $name = $this->getName();
    }

    // Validate name

    if ($name === null || $name === ''){
        return array('error' => 'File name empty.');
    }

    // Validate file size

    if ($size == 0){
        return array('error' => 'File is empty.');
    }

    if ($size > $this->sizeLimit){
        return array('error' => 'File is too large.');
    }

    // Validate file extension

    $pathinfo = pathinfo($name);
    $ext = isset($pathinfo['extension']) ? $pathinfo['extension'] : '';


    if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), array_map("strtolower", $this->allowedExtensions))){
        $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
        return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
    }



    // Save a chunk

    $totalParts = isset($_REQUEST['qqtotalparts']) ? (int)$_REQUEST['qqtotalparts'] : 1;

    if ($totalParts > 1){

        $chunksFolder = $this->chunksFolder;
        $partIndex = (int)$_REQUEST['qqpartindex'];
        $uuid = $_REQUEST['qquuid'];

        if (!is_writable($chunksFolder) && !is_executable($uploadDirectory)){
            return array('error' => "Server error. Chunks directory isn't writable or executable.");
        }

        $targetFolder = $this->chunksFolder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$uuid;

        if (!file_exists($targetFolder)){
            mkdir($targetFolder);
        }

        $target = $targetFolder.'/'.$partIndex;
        $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->inputName]['tmp_name'], $target);

        // Last chunk saved successfully
        if ($success AND ($totalParts-1 == $partIndex)){

            $target = $this->getUniqueTargetPath($uploadDirectory, $name);
            $this->uploadName = basename($target);

            $target = fopen($target, 'wb');

            for ($i=0; $i<$totalParts; $i++){
                $chunk = fopen($targetFolder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$i, "rb");
                stream_copy_to_stream($chunk, $target);
                fclose($chunk);
            }

            // Success
            fclose($target);

            for ($i=0; $i<$totalParts; $i++){
                unlink($targetFolder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$i);
            }

            rmdir($targetFolder);

            return array("success" => true);

        }

        return array("success" => true);

    } else {

        $target = $this->getUniqueTargetPath($uploadDirectory, $name);

        if ($target){
            $this->uploadName = basename($target);

            if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target)){
                return array('success'=> true);
            }
        }

        return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
            'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
    }
```

Comment: Yes, It's almost the same, but could you give me an example with the 3.5 version ?

Comment: Nothing has changed here in 3.5.  Simply return whatever data you like in your server response and access it as a property in the response parameter.

Comment: I can get the uploadName variable (responseJSON.uploadName), but I'm not sure how to get the foldername, cause the function is protected by default.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: I edit the post, I keep trying, I will find out ;)

Comment: This is a PHP question, not a Fine Uploader question.  I'll re-tag.